# Auto-Insert Days passed between date column on save or update

Tags: mysql, date, calculated-columns, difference

In a table I have following columns in a workdates table:

```
ID    StartDate    EndDate    NumDays
1     2014-05-03   2014-06-06 31
```

I would like NumDays column to auto-complete (auto-insert) number of days passed from the StartDate to EndDate on each new column or on each update of StartDate or EndDate columns. In the above example it is 31 days, but at this point I am manually entering it.

Do I have use trigger in this case and what type of column "Days" should be? Maybe something like this...

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tg_days_number_insert$$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_days_number_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON workdates
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE reg_add SET days = DATEDIFF(EndDate(),StartDate);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update doesn't correspond to your logic, because the update is on a different table, yet you seem to want the column set in `workdates`.  Is this what you want?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tg_days_number_insert$$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_days_number_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON workdates
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.days = DATEDIFF(NEW.EndDate, NEW.StartDate);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: My fault, I copied that trigger code from somewhere else. The table name is "workdates", and that's the one I want to work on. Also, I accidentally change your code (maybe it was correct though) instead of mine above. I have changed NEW.total_days to NEW.days assuming that "days" stays for "Days" column name.

Comment: @user3387040 . . . Perhaps it should be `numDays` as in the sample data in the question.  (I used `total_days` because it was in your sample code.)